# Program output that is neither STDOUT or STDERR?

Tags: python, bash, stdout, stderr

I'm getting some really strange behavior when trying to capture the output of django's manager.py

```
> ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:2869
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3.1, using settings 'polling.settings'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:2869/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That port is already in use.

> ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:2869 >stdout 2>stderr

> cat stderr
Error: That port is already in use.

> cat stdout

>
```

Why am I getting the empty string when I try to capture the output on the second run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any program could detect if its STDOUT and/or STDERR connected to terminal or not: man [isatty(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty). Python also has such a functionality: sys.stdout.isatty().

Probably your python script or its logging subsystem prints the lines that missing in the second run only when running on terminal i.e. in interactive mode. It's a common and proper practice. For example, there is no sense to print `"Quit the server with CONTROL-C"` if the output is redirected to a log file.

Below is a simple illustration:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print "Print always."
if sys.stdout.isatty():
  print "Print only on tty!"
```

Here we go:

```
$ ./test.py 
Print always.
Print only on tty!
$ ./test.py > log
$ cat log
Print always.
$
```

Comment: How could I detect if this is the case? Is there a way that I can call the program and set isatty() to true? (I assume that it's something like Bash that sets this)
Is there a way to at the very least "snoop" in on the output?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this is the case. You could check it by reading the script: for example, find string `"server is running at"` and look, how it is printed. Is there some test for `sys.stdout.isatty()` or does it uses some kind of log() instead of print(). If it does, then look for that `log()` code and so on.

You can not set isatty() to anything - the system does it. And there is nothing you can or should "snoop" - the script just **does not** print that lines when its output is redirected to a file. It just could detect whether the output is redirected or not.

Comment: What I meant is that if I set the output to STDOUT then I still get the output, is there a way to still somehow capture what is sent to STDOUT in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "set the output to STDOUT"? STDOUT **is** the standard output of the program. That means the standord print function(s) will output to it. At runtime that STDOUT could be "connected" to a terminal, to a regular file, to a pipe, etc. Program could determine, whether its STDOUT connected to the terminal or not and handle it according to its logic. For example, program could print or not print something to STDOUT. In this case, if you want to get all the output, you should change the program (script in your case). But I don't really understand, what for.